# Razor mutliselect dropdown- Set values as selected in the multiselect dropdown in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropbox

I need a way to set already selected values in a multi select dropdown in a edit view in a web application (ASP.NET, Mvc)

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Choose Categories</label>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Models.GetCategoryList().OrderBy(c => c.Value), "Key", "Value"), "Select Category", new { @class = "chzn-select form-control", multiple = "multiple" })                               
   </div>
```

this is view code, here I passed selected ids in to selected values array.(when I return values from DB , assign those in to a array then assign to here.

I need a edit view like this[image]

please anyone suggest way to do this

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you set the selected values in model.SelectedValues in the controller? That will ensure it gets selected in the View. If you are still having issues, can help if I see the controller method for the corresponding view.

Answer (score 0):

To generate this view you can use select2 jquery plugin. Check out the following link.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple